# Using custom jdbc driver in Superset

Tags: jdbc, apache-superset

I have a self-implemented Java service as a data-provider. I also have a JDBC JAR as driver to query data from my services. Normally, in DB tools like DBeaver, I can just add my JDBC JAR as a new driver and create a connection with a JDBC URL: `jdbc:mydriver://host:port/dbname` together with username and password.

Now the problem is, I want to use my driver to connect my service in Apache Superset. How should I do it?

I have looked https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/db-connection-ui/, but I'm still confused about how it works.

Comment: Given that page mentions SQLAlchemy, I rather suspect it is Python-based, and a JDBC driver is unlikely to work (or at least, not out of the box). They further indicate that for other database systems, you'll need to provide a custom implementation of a number of things. This is also confirmed on [this page](https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/installing-database-drivers), which says: _"Superset requires a Python DB-API database driver and a SQLAlchemy dialect to be installed for each datastore you want to connect to."_

Comment: My idea is to use my jdbc jar with sqlalchemy, i search and found example like https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-jdbc-generic/.  I'm still reading examples, not sure if it will work for me